# C# Enumerate Files 2 folders down using Directory.GetDirectories()

Tags: c#, directorysearcher

Using the EnumerateDirectories how do you enumerate only 2 folder structures down. Example: If I start at C:\, how do I get the folders inside of C as well as one additional level down?

The only thing that Directory.GetDirectories() offers so far is the SearchOption of

```
SearchOption.AllDirectories || SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
```

This is what I have so far:

```
private static List<string> GetDirectories(string path, string searchPattern = "*")
    {
        try
        {
            return Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why call `.ToList()` here? why not just return `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I guess I could do that, I would have to figure out what benefits that gives me over     .ToList()

Comment: You can't automatically, but you could do it quite easily using a loop

Comment: @Kevin So you think loop the "AllDirectories" Enum and then have a counter, while counter = 2, quit?

Comment: The benefits are reduced memory usage, and potential faster execution.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you, I will look into this, appreciate the heads up!

Comment: Have a look at this article - this is the right way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874516/how-to-limit-the-depth-of-a-recursive-sub-directory-search

Comment: When you use SearchOption.AllDirectories on C:\ then you are guaranteed to catch that exception and get nothing.  It has a hidden directory named System Volume Information, that is where restore point data is saved.  Even an admin doesn't have access to it by default.  You'll have to recurse yourself, stay away from directories that have FileAttributes.System set.  Also always want you want if you are only interested in 2 levels deep.  And important since a 3 terabyte drive can take many minutes to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You use a counter for the level and call the method recursively.

Untested code:

```
private static List<string> GetDirectories(string path, int level, string searchPattern = "*")
{
    if (level == 0)
        return Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
    else
    {
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        foreach (string path2 in Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            l.AddRange(GetDirectories(path2, level - 1, searchPattern));
        return l;
    }
}
```

and call like this:

```
return GetDirectories(yourPath, 1, yourSearchPattern);
```

or you can change this to drill down, then go back up for the next etc. but still using a counter.

If you need the files (though the body of your question didn't mention that, only the title), just iterate over the result, getting the files in each of the folders you got.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, you'll just need to add some code if you're not authorized to access the directory.

```
                    Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern).ToList().ForEach(
                    d =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            searchItems.Add(d);
                            searchItems.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(d, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
                        }
                        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                        {
                            //do something when you are not authorized
                        }
                    });
```