# Recursively search directories n directories deep

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to find all files in a directory with a certain extension.

I'm using the following code:

```
string dir = "C:\temp"
FileInfo[] fsis = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.cfg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The problem is that some directories contain many nested directories so it takes a very long time. Assuming that I know all .cfg files will only be up to n directories deep is there any way I can modify the above code to only search that far or will I have to write from scratch my own recursive file finder?

Comment: Do you know how to write a recursive function?  Pass in a `DirectoryInfo` and the depth remaining.  If the depth remaining is greater than zero, search sub-folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Limit The Depth of a Recursive Sub-Directory Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874516/how-to-limit-the-depth-of-a-recursive-sub-directory-search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<FileInfo> FindFiles(List<FileInfo> results, string dir, int depth)
{
    // Get all cfg files in current directory
    results.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.cfg"));

    if(depth > 1)
    {
        // Recurse in all subdirectories
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetDirectories())
        {
            // But dont go as deep in those subdirectories
            FindFiles(results, d.FullName, depth - 1);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

And then you can call

```
List<FileInfo> = FindFiles(new List<FileInfo>(), "C:\Example", 5);
```